# why does ServiceStack.Text not use ModelFactory for lists?

Tags: c#, reflection, servicestack, servicestack-text

I think I found a bug in ServiceStack.Text. I added this test (below) to the CustomSerializerTests file. You'll notice that it works for deserializing a single item, but the constructor is not called when deserializing the (i)list. (Changing from IList to List makes the test pass.) How do I make this work with IList?

Update: in looking further at the ReflectionExtensions, I don't understand why you differentiate "New" from "CreateInstance". All calls to CreateInstance should use the ModelFactory if possible, true? It looks like there are more methods for creating instances than are necessary.

Update 2: I've been looking into refactoring the ReflextionExtensions to make this work. However, I can't seem to see a way to make it work with all existing tests. Some existing tests for ModelFactory call the ReflextionExtensions.CreateInstance method. Anything I would change to make this work would cause CreateInstance to use the ModelFactory. Hence, we go into an infinite loop on those existing tests. If the tests returned the default value of ModelFactory instead of calling CreateInstance directly, it would work.

```
class MyImmutable
{
    public readonly double Const = 42;
    public double Value { get; protected set; }
    protected MyImmutable() {} // for serialization
    public MyImmutable(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

[Test]
public void ProtectedConstructorsAreCalled()
{
    using (JsConfig.With(modelFactory: type =>
    {
        if (type.IsValueType)
            return () => Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        var ctors = from ctor in type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                    let prms = ctor.GetParameters()
                    where prms.All(p => p.IsOptional)
                    orderby prms.Length
                    select ctor;

        var constructor = ctors.FirstOrDefault();

        if (constructor == null)
        {
            ctors = from ctor in type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                    let prms = ctor.GetParameters()
                    where prms.All(p => p.IsOptional)
                    orderby prms.Length
                    select ctor;

            constructor = ctors.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (constructor != null)
            return () => constructor.Invoke(new object[0]);

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }))
    {
        var immut = new MyImmutable(23);
        var json = immut.ToJson();
        var immut2 = json.FromJson<MyImmutable>();

        Assert.AreEqual(immut.Const, immut2.Const); // this assert is fine
        Assert.AreEqual(immut.Value, immut2.Value);

        IList<MyImmutable> immutables = new List<MyImmutable>{immut};

        json = immutables.ToJson();
        var immutables2 = json.FromJson<IList<MyImmutable>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < immutables.Count; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(immutables[i].Const, immutables2[i].Const); // fails on this assert
            Assert.AreEqual(immutables[i].Value, immutables2[i].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - How do I make this work with IList? You can probably get it to work but IList isn't marked with the Serializable attribute nor inherits from ISerializable so it isn't really meant to be serializable.